# Collectd and exec: line 1329 near `<newline>': syntax error, unexpected EOL

Tags: collectd

Trying to use exec plugin with collectd:

`/etc/collectd.conf`:

```
...
LoadPlugin exec
...
<Plugin exec>
        Exec "nobody:nobody" "/etc/collectd.d/redis_simple.sh"
</Plugin>
```

I've simplified `/etc/collectd.d/redis_simple.sh` to this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while sleep 10
do
        echo "PUTVAL nfs/redis-6379/memcached_items-db0 interval=10 N:3043"
done
```

The error:

```
# /etc/init.d/collectd restart
Stopping collectd:                                         [  OK  ]
Starting collectd: Parse error in file `/etc/collectd.d/redis.sh', line 1308 near `<newline>': syntax error, unexpected EOL
yyparse returned error #1
configfile: Cannot read file `/etc/collectd.d/redis.sh'.
Parse error in file `/etc/collectd.d/redis_simple.sh', line 1329 near `<newline>': syntax error, unexpected EOL
yyparse returned error #1
configfile: Cannot read file `/etc/collectd.d/redis_simple.sh'.
=                                                          [  OK  ]

                                                      [  OK  ]
```

There definitely is the new line at the end of both files. No windows EOLs. Nothing in logs. No line 1329 in /etc/collectd.d/redis_simple.sh.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need your `redis_simple.sh` (and `redis.sh`) to be moved out of `/etc/collectd.d`, so collectd doesn't try parsing these as configuration files

Or: look at your `collectd.conf`, there may be something like `Include "/etc/collectd.d/*"` that you may replace with `Include "/etc/collectd.d/*.conf`"